# What is the best practice for long promise chainings within Promise.All

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird, es6-promise

Suppose I have several main promises, some of which return promise inside. I want to retrieve results from sort of promise functions that why I think about `Promise.all`. First off, let take a look at my example code below

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
promise = []
function promise1(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    console.log('promise1');
    resolve('promise1');
  });
}
function promise2(){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log('promise2');
    resolve('promise2');
  });
}
function promise3(){
  promise2().then(function(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('promise3');
      resolve('promise3')
    })
  })
}
```

Upper piece of code, 2 main promises are `promise1` and `promise3`. `promise2` will be returned by `promise3`. I'm demonstating `promise3` as a long promise chaning. To run, I initialized

```
promise = [promise1(), promise3()];
Promise.all(promise).then(function(data){
  console.log('done', data);
})
```

Outcome was

> promise1
>
> promise2
>
> promise3
>
> done [ 'promise1', undefined ]

but I am expecting that

> done [ 'promise1', 'promise3' ]

My question is what is the best practice in this case?

Comment: Regarding the update, please ask only one question per post. Rather [post a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: You did not implement halcyon's change correctly. You're returning the promise **before** the `.then` on promise3. Check your code again.

Comment: @torazaburo: it's just another discussion, will separate it as Bergi suggested

Comment: We don't need another discussion. Just run the code that Halcyon suggested. It works. Then you can accept his answer and we can all move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`promise3` is missing a `return`. With this it works as expected.

```
function promise3(){
  return promise2().then(function(){
  // ^^^ missing return here
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      console.log('promise3');
      resolve('promise3')
    })
  })
}
```

---

Update:

If you simplify your case you're doing:

```
var a = new Promise(function(resolve) {
  resolve("a");
});
var b = a.then(function () {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve("b");
  }));
});
```

And then your question is: *"why is the resolved value of `a` not equal to `b`?"*. Well, they're two different promises.

With `return a` you return the original `promise2`. In `a.then` you eventually return `promise3`.

Comment: thanks, it really helps. But i have updated my question, could u pls check

Comment: does it mean if I want `promise3` return, i have to `return promise2().then(function(){})`